# sqlite configuring with django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, database-design

I have been assigned the task of setting up an online database with sqlite via django- where it will contain columns of information. My problem is that I can't figure out which is establishing table where the information will go- my models.py script or should I do it with a "CREATE TABLE" command?
An example of the code in my models.py script is below:

```
    class Person(models.Model):
       firstname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
       lastname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The tutorial that I was given recommended this command:

```
    insert into freezer_person (firstname,last name) values('Louis','Pasteur')
```

However upon executing this command I naturally got an error saying "table does not exist" i.e. I have to use the "CREATE TABLE" command.
so when I tried:

```
           "CREATE TABLE in freezer_person(...)"
```

It returned that "in" was syntactically incorrect.
So my question is how do I go about creating a table that will intake info from models.py?- I can't seem to find any info on this...

Comment: What tutorial are you using? Is there nothing about django's migrations (or the old version `syncdb`)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't create the tables; Django does it for you, through the [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/) system.

This is all fully covered in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/).

Answer (score 0):

Your model classes from **models.py** define your tables: each model class will be transposed in a table. Each property of a model class will be a column in the corresponding table. Each instance of the model class will be a row in that table.

So when you want to create a table you define a model class in the models.py file of your app, then run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

which tracks the changes made to the model class and generate a migration file which contains the sql statements to be applied to the database, and then to apply them to the database, you run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have made all the necessary migrations and inserted values to the table- "select * from freezer_person;" however does not return anything....